# How to stop Vue.js CLI commenting out SVG favicon in the [if IE] tag?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, progressive-web-apps

I've created a new application with Vue CLI and I'm using the following code in my index.html to embed an SVG icon.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="any" href="/img/icons/icon.svg">
```

This on it's own should work without any issues.

However, when Vue builds the application, I can see this line gets commented out in the source code.
Regular (png) icons work just fine without being wrapped in the  [if IE] tag.

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" sizes="any" href="/img/icons/icon.svg"><![endif]-->
```

I would like my original code to be used instead of it being wrapped in the [if IE] tag, is there any way to tell Vue not to edit it?

EDIT: Here's the code to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/CerxMe/vue-icon-bug

Comment: This is something to do with the PWA plugin. See the code here ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/packages/@vue/cli-plugin-pwa/lib/HtmlPwaPlugin.js#L64